# Downgrade after failed Catalina install?

Tags: catalina, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an iMac to Catalina and the upgrade process keeps failing. macOS is not booting back into Mojave either.

I have already tried the following:

- Disk utility first-aid
- SMC reset
- NVRAM reset

Is there a way to get back into Mojave or get the Catalina upgrade going again?

Comment: What was the failure. what did you try to either fix Catalina’s installation or install Mojave?  do you have a Time Machine backup?  What Mac model?  What version were you upgrading from if not Mojave?

Comment: The installer just says macOS could not be installed in your computer. It could not remove the previous OS. And then it reboots. After rebooting I get a black screen in every language saying there's a problem booting the computer and it keeps crashing again there on every boot.

Comment: I was upgrading an iMac late 2013 from the latest Mojave.

Comment: Please understand that we cant see over your shoulder.  Vague and incomplete descriptions can’t help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I decided to give up and start over by erasing the disk. Unfortunately the installer didn't say anything further from what I described. The screen that was coming up is the one described in this link as Un-Assigned Kernel Misfiring (i.e. kernel panic): https://appletoolbox.com/macbook-will-not-start-macos-sierra-update-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to the issue. At the last stage of the installation process the installer informed that it couldn't remove the previous version of macOS and rebooted.

After that, macOS enter in an infinite loop of kernel panic upon every boot. Gave up, erased the disk and installed from USB.

Perhaps the solution under `Un-Assigned Kernel Misfiring` on this [link](https://appletoolbox.com/macbook-will-not-start-macos-sierra-update-fix/) could have solved my issue, but I only found it after reinstalling macOS from scratch.